# Как избавиться от обновления MainActivity при повороте устройства?

Tags: android

Добрый день, в методе

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  }
```

при запуске приложения вызываю необходимые методы для его работы, но заметил как только поверну устройство переворачивается и главное Activity, а с ним все методы что были вызваны раннее вызываются повторно как будто приложение запустили заново как можно этого избежать ? 
Есть вариант заблокировать Activity от поворотов, но это грубо и что то типа это кого

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

так же использовать не хочется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При перевороте устройства экземпляр `activity` пересоздается, соотвественно требуется как то сохранять данные и заново их инициализировать (если они конечно были).

Воспользуйтесь методами: onSaveInstanceState или onRetainNonConfigurationInstance - они помогут вам сохранить ваши данные и восстановить их.

Но это в случае если вы ходите избежать потери данных. Для запрета смены ориентации (которая так же избавит от данной проблемы) существуют другие решения.

UPD. Вот эту страничку даже перевели на русский:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html?hl=ru

UPD2. И эту тоже! 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html